# SSIS error when configuring .xls data flow task Excel 5.0/95

Tags: excel, ssis, oledb

Quick environment details: Windows 64 bit Server 2008; SQL Server 2012; Visual Studio 2012

I have a SSIS package that we are trying to connect to a .xls file (5.0/95 version, not 97-2003) via the MS access driver. So we use this connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=MyFile.xls;Extended Properties="EXCEL 5.0;HDR=YES";
```

We have a problem retrieving the sheets on the Origin Excel data flow task.

There is the next message when we try open the excel table or view, and it says that it could not load any table or view.

Then we tried using a SQL Command and showed the next message:

> "Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.PipelineUtils.GetActiveConnection(ConnectionManager
>   connectionManager, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Control control,
>   IsConnectionCurrentCallback IsConnectionCurrent)    en
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.PipelineUtils.GetCompleteConnectionString(ConnectionManager
>   connectionManager, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)    en
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DataFlowUI.DataFlowConnectionPage.buildSqlQueryButton_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)"

We tried running the project in 32 bit mode, install the AccessDatabaseEngine.exe but the result was the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: You installed the AccessDatabaseEngine and you have still used the Jet OLE DB Provider? The sense in installing the AccessDatabaseEngine is to use the (newly available) "Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Dabase Engine OLE DB Provider", which should work for Excel too.

Comment: The problem is that it does not work with Excels saved as 5.0/95 xls versión..

With 97-2003 or 2007 versions it works but our requirement needs to be with that file version

Comment: My only thought would be you need an earlier version of the AccessDatabaseEngine that does support Excel 5.0 in order to install you will most likley have to remove the newer versions that you have already installed.  If you need the newer versions you can install them after the fact.